# saving date in mongodb using python

Tags: python, mongodb, date, datetime

I have a field, `'date'` that I take from a document. 
The field `date` has a value like this: `"01.01.2014"`.

I'm saving this field into a mongo database like this:

```
"date" : "01.01.2014",
```

If I split those parameters I have:

```
year ='2014' 
month ='01' 
day ='01'
```

I want to save this field in proper type like datetime so how can I store it using those parameters?

Answer (score 1):

Use module [datetime](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html)

your date object to be saved in mongoDB would be

```
myDateObject = datetime.datetime(year,month,day, 0 , 0)
```

use `myDateObject` to store as a value for date key in mongoDB.

Here year, month and day are expected to be integer.

As in your question, you can also use the date field to convert it to python datetime. Assuming date is in mm.dd.yyyy format, the code to convert date into datetime object is,

```
>>> datetime.datetime.strptime(date,"%m.%d.%Y")
datetime.datetime(2014, 1, 1, 0, 0)
```